# Getting XML Schema from MS SQL Database

Tags: .net, database, sql-server-2005, xsd, ndbunit

Is it possible to generate a XML Schema of a Database programatically with .Net and C#? I want to look into NDbUnit but for big databases it would not really be feasible to make a Schema manually?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is it possible to generate a XML
>   Schema from a Database?

It sure is, [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/dev_portal_xml_schema.html) can generate XML Schema from a database.

There's [another way](http://dwightrau.blogspot.com/2008/02/generate-or-create-xsd-schema-from.html), though I've never tested it:

```
create table Person
(
Age int not NULL check( Age > 0) ,
Height numeric(10,2) not NULL check( Height > 5),
Gender varchar(5) not null check( Gender in ('M', 'F', 'O')),
BirthDate datetime null,
)

DECLARE @schema xml
SET @schema = (SELECT * FROM Person FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA('PersonSchema'))
select @schema
```

Comment: Small note to the native method: that query will indeed return the XML schema of the table, but also any data in it.  To get only the schema, replace "SELECT * FROM" with "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM".

Answer (score 2):

I could do it like this:

```
DataSet results = new DataSet();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", new SqlConnection(connectionString));

SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

sqlAdapter.FillSchema(results, SchemaType.Mapped);//Fills dataset with schema from query
results.WriteXmlSchema(mySchema);
```

Problem is, how could I adapt this method so that it could be used with a indeterminate amount of tables? Without building up a string though concatenation which is not exactly ideal!

Answer (score -1):

Use MyGeneration's typed-dataset-template to auto-generate the XSD (http://www.mygenrationssoftware.com).  Its free, OSS, and works great.  Also, the NDbUnit team is presently working on an add-on tool to NDbUnit that will make it possible to not only extract the schema from the database, but also to edit the test data that is contained within the accompanying XML dataset.  ETA for this tool is about mid-July.