# Get XML schema from database schema (SQL Server 2008 diagram)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xsd

Get XML schema from database schema (SQL Server 2008 diagram)

I am using SQL Server 2008. Is their is a way to do this in the SQL studio enterprise manager?

[Rather than write code or use an external tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298660/getting-xml-schema-from-ms-sql-database)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management studio doesn't provide a way to do this.

Pasting the following into a code window gives you something close:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for xml auto
```

Failing that, the answer is no, not without writing code or using an external tool.