# How to create XML/XSD from SQL table with multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, xml, schema, xsd

How to create XML/XSD from SQL table with multiple tables

what I want to do is create an XML schema from a database (or database schema)

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298660/getting-xml-schema-from-ms-sql-database) has some interesting code

Particularly

```
DataSet results = new DataSet();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", new SqlConnection(connectionString));

SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

sqlAdapter.FillSchema(results, SchemaType.Mapped);//Fills dataset with schema from query
results.WriteXmlSchema(mySchema);
```

But how do I generate this XML schema from multiple tables? If I just do

```
Select * from table1,table2
```

All of the data is in one big blob in the XML

What I want is each table defined in the XML with it's contents separately. 
  something

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the schema for each table separately, and combine it using an XDocument.  Here's a function to grab a schema from a database query:

```
XDocument GrabSchema(
   string dataSetName,
   string sql)
{
   var con = new SqlConnection("<<YourConnectionString>>");
   var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
   var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
   var dataSet = new DataSet(dataSetName);
   sqlAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   dataSet.WriteXmlSchema(stream);
   stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
   return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(stream));
}
```

You then combine the two table schemas like:

```
var firstSchema = GrabDataset("t1", "select a = 49");
var secondSchema = GrabDataset("t2", "select b = '50'");
firstSchema.Root.Add(secondSchema.Root.Elements());
```

You can verify the combined schema makes sense by loading it into another DataSet:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(firstSchema.CreateReader());
```

Comment: That is very helpful I think but how do I write back to a physical file?

On the readXMLSchema I get a
"Invalid XPath selection inside field node....."

DataSet _completeDataSet = new DataSet();
            _completeDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(vehicleSchema.CreateReader());

          _completeDataSet.WriteXmlSchema("FleetsDatabaseSchema.xsd");