# How do I extract a database schema using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to extract an XML schema from a database (a "database schema") using a T-SQL query in SQL management studio, rather than C# code. The schema should include all tables in the database.

I can get a single table using the following:

```
DECLARE @schema xml
SET @schema = (SELECT * FROM Student FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA('StudentSchema'))
select @schema
```

But how do I combine the remaining tables? All of my tables are related in some way.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638177/how-to-create-xml-xsd-from-sql-table-with-multiple-tables), which discusses how to do it in code.

Comment: What do you mean by `using a T-SQL query, rather than code`??

Comment: I should have clarified. I edited the post.

Comment: makes much more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could alway use `sp_msforeachtable` and dynamic sql:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable '
DECLARE @schema xml
SET @schema = (SELECT * FROM ? FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA(''?Schema''))
select @schema
'
```

You may have a naming issue with the schema name since I think you will have `dbo.` or schema prefix to the table name.

Comment: This gets me a set of .XSDs, one for each table. Can I combine them somehow with T-SQL? i.e., if 2 tables are related by a 1-Many relationship, one of the tables should have an element made up on children of the other. Is this reasonable and achievable? Thx!

Comment: Not with the query I gave you.  You could potentially write some much more complicated dynamic SQL looking at the metadata for this, but it seems like it would be fraught with peril.

Comment: Haha you've described my Monday to a T. I'll have to figure something else out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Retrodrone - happy to help.  with your requirements you may want to look into third party tools, like those from Redgate.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [Information Schema Views (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
FOR XML AUTO
```