# NDBUnit schema error

Tags: c#, ndbunit

I've been searching for an answer for quite some time without any luck.

I'm using NDbUnit for my test data and I want to be able to generate my XSD files automatically. I don't want to have to regenerate my XSD files each time I add a new property to my classes. So my plan is to automatically generate the XSD files using the XsdDataContractExporter class since some of my classes contain IList and I got some errors using the xml serializer.

this is the code I got so far:

```
XsdDataContractExporter exporter = new XsdDataContractExporter();
exporter.Export(typeof(Supplier));

//XmlQualifiedName xmlQualifiedName = exporter.GetRootElementName(typeof(Supplier));
foreach (XmlSchema schema in exporter.Schemas.Schemas()) {
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(String.Format(@"..\..\data\{0}.xsd", GetSchemaName(schema)), new XmlWriterSettings() {
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Indent = true,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = false
});

foreach (XmlSchemaObject include in schema.Includes) {
    XmlSchemaImport importedSchema = include as XmlSchemaImport;
    if (importedSchema != null) {
        ArrayList lst = new ArrayList(exporter.Schemas.Schemas(importedSchema.Namespace));
        XmlSchema actualImportedSchema = (XmlSchema)lst[0];
        importedSchema.Schema = actualImportedSchema;
        importedSchema.SchemaLocation = Path.GetFullPath(String.Format(@"..\..\data\{0}.xsd", GetSchemaName(actualImportedSchema)));
    }
}
schema.Write(writer);
writer.Close();
}
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema(@"..\..\data\business.model.supplier.xsd");
```

the problem is that I get an error when reading the schema which is:

```
failed: System.InvalidOperationException : Nested table 'SupplierCategory' which inherits its namespace cannot have multiple parent tables in different namespaces.
```

The bottom line is, I want to use a dynamically generated XSD file from a type to use with NDBUnit to populate my database with test data. Is this the right approach ? This is the schema that are generated and that gives my the error:

Supplier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Model.Supplier" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Model.Supplier" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="C:\dev\skeleton\branches\dev\src\testconsole\data\business.model.supplier.category.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Model.Supplier.Category" />
  <xs:import schemaLocation="C:\dev\skeleton\branches\dev\src\testconsole\data\arrays.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
  <xs:complexType name="Supplier">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Categories" nillable="true" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Model.Supplier.Category" type="q1:ArrayOfSupplierCategory" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Comments" nillable="true" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" type="q2:ArrayOfstring" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Supplier" nillable="true" type="tns:Supplier" />
</xs:schema>
```

SupplierCategory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Model.Supplier.Category" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Business.Model.Supplier.Category" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfSupplierCategory">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SupplierCategory" nillable="true" type="tns:SupplierCategory" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfSupplierCategory" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSupplierCategory" />
  <xs:complexType name="SupplierCategory">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="SupplierCategory" nillable="true" type="tns:SupplierCategory" />
</xs:schema>
```

Any advice would be great !
Thx,
Franck

Comment: the funny thing is, i thought about writing a custom component that would only read a xml file and do something like `insert into _table_ values (_value1_, _value2_, etc...)`. because my database schema is already taken care of by the export feature of nhibernate, all I need to do is put some data in there.

Answer (score 0):

See the list of suggestions in this post [Getting XML Schema from MS SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298660/getting-xml-schema-from-ms-sql-database) (specifically the top-voted answer) but also note my suggestion of using MyGeneration to achieve the same thing.

Comment: yeah I tried downloading this tool but there is not much documentation about how to use it in command line to generate XSDs from C# classes... so I'm trying my chances with my homemade testing framework !

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem I've also been facing quite a time later, as we were using NDbUnit for integration tests in our project – ended up with a custom library, which doesn't need a schema to be defined separately, it reads it from database on its own. Library is [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed).