# T-SQL : getting the column descriptions into a XMLSCHEMA

Tags: t-sql, xml-schema-collection

I have a query where I generate a XMLSCHEMA and a XML sample.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    filename, queue, owner, resubmitFile, 
    pages, system, created, server, preflightlogs, status, kit, totalkits
FROM 
    Preflight_analytics
FOR XML AUTO, XMLSCHEMA ('Preflight_analytics')
```

All my columns have a description associated with it.

Is it possible to get the column description place inside the xsd like the below sample? I use the xsd to generate documentation and the tool I use, uses the tag `<xsd:documentation>` to add the description to the docs - like below:

```
<xsd:attribute name="JobID" fixed="" use="required">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Vendors unique ID</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033"
        sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth"
        sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
        <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:attribute
```

I been looking over the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/generate-an-inline-xsd-schema?view=sql-server-ver16) haven't found anything yet but still looking.

Thank you
Mike

Comment: Must you use XMLSCHEMA or could you query information schema like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520448/how-to-create-xml-schema-from-an-existing-database-in-sql-server-2008) ?

Comment: This is how the XML SCHEMA was created.